# In randomly organized data set, find corresponding value in other spreadsheet and change colors

Tags: vba, loops, excel, filtering

I have two sheets. Both of them have over 11,000 rows of mutually exclusive data - with the exception of a few. I need to find what values within D1 are held within D0. I have the following Macro written for it. It keeps freezing and going very slow, so to be completely honest, I don't even know if it is working. Since they only have a tiny bit of data similar, and they're going to constantly change, I assume I can't organize it and filter it that way. Also, I need to avoid using vlookup. Thanks for any help!

```
Sub FindMatches()
Dim Nova As Workbook
Dim D0 As Worksheet
Dim D1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow0 As Long
Dim LastRow1 As Long

Set Nova = Workbooks("Nova")
Set D0 = Nova.Sheets("D0")
Set D1 = Nova.Sheets("D-1")

LastRow0 = D0.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = D1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To LastRow0
    For Z = 2 To LastRow1
        If D0.Range("A" & i) = D1.Range("A" & Z) Then
        D0.Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        Else: End If
    Next Z
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH() is usually better than nested loops:

```
Sub FindMatches()
    Dim Nova As Workbook
    Dim D0 As Worksheet
    Dim D1 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngVals As Range, rngSrch As Range

    Set Nova = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("Nova")
    Set D0 = Nova.Sheets("D0")
    Set D1 = Nova.Sheets("D-1")

    Set rngVals = D0.Range(D0.Range("A2"), D0.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rngSrch = D1.Range(D1.Range("A2"), D1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In rngVals
        'EDIT: hiliting matches, not non-matches
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rngSrch, 0)) Then
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        End If

    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```